# "ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'School Diary.app/NewEventsCustomTableViewCell.o' is not permitted"

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode12

ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'School Diary.app/NewEventsCustomTableViewCell.o' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

while uploading app to app store in Xcode12 getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy all the content of the NewEventsCustomTableViewCell.swift file. Delete the file. Make a new file give same name and paste in the copied text of the deleted file.
This will solve your problem.